# github actions firebase No project active, but project aliases are available

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, devops, github-actions

I have created a workflow to build react app to the production.

```
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    env:
      REACT_APP_ENV: live build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting:production
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

Build job is running correctly. But for the deploy, I got this error

> Error: No project active, but project aliases are available.
>
> Run firebase use  with one of these options:

My `.firebaserc` file

```
{
  "projects": {
    "production": "gottamenu-admin",
    "development":"gotta-menu-ap"
  }
}
```

I follow instructions on the firebase repo for GitHub actions

If you have multiple hosting environments you can specify which one in the args line.  e.g. args: deploy --only hosting:[environment name]

That's why I put `args: deploy --only hosting:production`

How do I fix this error in GitHub action?

Answer (score 0):

Use `deploy --only hosting:production` if you want to deploy different sites (targets) on the same firebase-project

And your `.firebaserc` should look like

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "gottamenu-admin"
  },
  "targets": {
    "gottamenu-admin": {
      "hosting": {
        "production": [
          "gottamenu-admin",
        ],
        "development": [
          "gotta-menu-ap"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to deploy to different firebase-projects
then your `.firebaserc` file is correct but
you should use `deploy -P production` or `deploy --project production`